# Getting an error "java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfWeek"

Tags: java, scala, selenium

I have used this, but I don't know why I'm getting this error while trying to extract the current month in the format "MMM,YYYY""

```
val thisMonth = YearMonth.now()
val lastMonth = thisMonth.minusMonths(1)
val last12thMonth = thisMonth.minusMonths(12)

val monthYearFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM,YYYY")
val lastMonthinWords = lastMonth.format(monthYearFormatter)
Reporter.log("Last month is "+lastMonthinWords)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408688/unsupportedtemporaltypeexception-unsupported-field-instantseconds)

Comment: @AlexeyR. thanks for the help, I got the solution now.